# Getting error in git update

Tags: java, git, openshift

I'm using `RedHat Openshift` cloud.

I have done one thing(perhaps a blunder :( ) : From my `java & webapp` folder,I deleted my whole packages and again copy paste that packages in to `java & webapp` folder.

Issue: Now whenever I'm trying to update my app from command prompt: like

```
`git add .` 

`git commit -m "My message"`
```

//Here I'm getting error i.e.

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

`git push //Can't goto the 3rd step.`

Any solution ...... for update my latest code.

Comment: I don't get it. If you remove the folder and put it again, why would there be a change to commit ?

Comment: you are right,but in openshift using git...it's showing,so how to set these last in terms of git command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this process, i hope it could help you

```
git checkout master

git branch test

git checkout test

git push origin test

git add (files to add)

git commit -m "Message"

git push origin +test
```

Try this for merge with master:

```
git checkout master

git merge test
```

Comment: Big thanks for your reply ....git add **.**,what does this dot mean?...and there are so many files inside the package then...should I have to add it separately ??

Comment: git add . means "add all the new or changed files in my local branch to the staging area"

Comment: @user1645434 get into the package root dir which need to add, use ` git add .` to add entire directory,

Comment: Getting error in 6th step:< C:\Users\User\security>git commit -m "Commit_1"
# On branch test
nothing to commit (working directory clean) >

Comment: Are you deleted in master or in branch ?if you have deleted in branch there is no need to do the commit  process or  if you have deleted in master just create a branch , commit the required files , merge with branch

Comment: deleted in master,if it requres to merge , could you please update your answer with merge with master/branch(I'm novish in git)